# How to add stripplot under boxplot (by default it is always on top) in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, boxplot

It seems that stripplot (or swarmplot) are automatically always added on top of boxplot even if I call one function in front of the other.

Am I missing something here? How to make stripplot be behind the boxplot? Also, I am actually only using boxplots to use the 'mean' with diamond marker.

Here is a sample code for how I pretty much call the functions now:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5, 4), dpi=200)
sns.boxplot(ax=axs, data=df, x='region', y='measure', hue='group',
            meanprops={'marker' : 'D', 'markeredgecolor' : 'black', 'markersize' : 6},
            medianprops={'visible': False}, whiskerprops={'visible': False},
            showmeans=True, showfliers=False, showbox=False, showcaps=False)
sns.stripplot(ax=axs, data=df, x='region', y='measure', hue='group',
              dodge=True, jitter=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[The plot currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2FGA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `sns.stripplot(..., zorder=0)` to put the strip plot below the other elements.

To have the mean in the legend, you can add a `label`. As this will label each individual mean, you can collect all the legend handles, and filter out the first of those, together with the `PathCollection`s that represent the dots of the `stripplot`, also leaving out the rectangles that represent the left-out boxes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections  import PathCollection
from matplotlib.lines  import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
sns.boxplot(ax=axs, data=tips, x='day', y='tip', hue='smoker',
            meanprops={'marker' : 'D', 'markeredgecolor' : 'black', 'markersize' : 6, 'label':'mean'},
            medianprops={'visible': False}, whiskerprops={'visible': False},
            showmeans=True, showfliers=False, showbox=False, showcaps=False)
sns.stripplot(ax=axs, data=tips, x='day', y='tip', hue='smoker', palette='autumn',
              dodge=True, jitter=0.05, zorder=0)
handles, _ = axs.get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handles = [h for h in handles if isinstance(h, PathCollection)] + [h for h in handles if isinstance(h, Line2D)][:1]
axs.legend(handles=new_handles, title=axs.legend_.get_title().get_text())
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.stripplot below sns.boxplot]

Comment: This works perfectly! 'zorder=0' was what was missing from my function. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

if you want two and more plot use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20, 15))
```

And use ax=ax[0,1], row and col,

```
sns.boxplot(x = 'bedrooms', y = 'price', data = dataset_df, ax=ax[0,1])
sns.boxplot(x = 'floor, y = 'price', data = dataset_df,  ax=ax[0,2])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want them on one plot, not separate plots. Just stripplot behind the boxplot, like in the background layer.

Comment: Can you show pictures? Please links and maybe i help you. If you one plot do not usenrows=1, ncols=1 and ax. Run two plot as one.

Comment: I just used subplots, because originally I actually have two plots next to each other, but the current problem doesn't involve that. The main issue is that when you would run sns.boxplot(data=df, x=x, y=y) and sns.stripplot(data=df, x=x, y=y) or the opposite order, you would also get stripplot being on top of the boxplot (thereby hiding part of the boxplot). Is it possible to do it that the stripplot is on bottom (thereby, behind the boxplot)?

Comment: you have use many function, can you try only:  fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
sns.stripplot(ax=axs, data=df, x='Sex', y='Age')
sns.boxplot(ax=axs, data=df, x='Sex', y='Age',)
plt.show()

Comment: if you try this code you can show better

Comment: yeah, i've tried it like this. It still shows stripplot on top of the boxplot.

Comment: is this want you?   picture:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ISd.png

Comment: Just the opposite. This is what I get now, but I want the stripplot BEHIND the boxplot.

Comment: sorry, my last code but do not work :   fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
sns.set(style="ticks")

sns.boxplot(ax=axs, data=dfff, x='Sex', y='Age',  linewidth=1)
sns.swarmplot(ax=axs, data=dff, x='Sex', y='Age',size=4, edgecolor="gray", split=True)

Comment: nope, it's the same solution with only sns.set(style='ticks') added, but it doesnt fix this :/